# SVM + HOG, found object is always NULL

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, svm, detection

I am working on fungus spores detection. I have about 359 positive images(cropped images of fungus particles) and 171 negative images(cropped images of dust particles).

the actual size of pos/nag images is same as the size of particle which is around 8x8 but for SVM training I have resize it to 30x30 and then have used resized images to train SVM classifier. I am directly training the SVM with images not with any features.

After training the classifier successfully I used hog.setSVMDetector(myclassifier) and hog.detectMultiScale but the found objects is zero.

Now my questions is what I am doing wrong in my code? 
Please click on the below link for Nagative/Positive images which I used for SVM classifier, test images and the desired particles image.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7yRjtOGywg7fnNJTXcxR2NYb3ItWTZ0UjYwUmt6YW96R0NHLWZQbVJucEk0bnJmcFJGS0E&usp=sharing

```
class LinearSVM: public CvSVM {
public:

  void getSupportVector(std::vector<float>& support_vector) const;
};  

void LinearSVM::getSupportVector(std::vector<float>& support_vector) const {

    int sv_count = this->get_support_vector_count();
 //   mexPrintf("size :   %d\n",support_vector.size());
    const CvSVMDecisionFunc* df = this->decision_func;
    const double* alphas = df[0].alpha;
    double rho = df[0].rho;
    int var_count = this->get_var_count();
    support_vector.resize(var_count, 0);
    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < (unsigned)sv_count; r++) {
      float myalpha = alphas[r];
      const float* v = this->get_support_vector(r);
      for (int j = 0; j < var_count; j++,v++) {
        support_vector[j] += (-myalpha) * (*v);
      }
    }
    support_vector.push_back(rho);
}

////////////////////////////// main.cpp ///////////////////////////
    int num_files = 359*171;
int img_area = 30*30;
Mat training_mat(num_files,img_area,CV_32FC1);
vector<int> training_Labels;
Mat labels(num_files,1,CV_32FC1);
int imagenum=0;
 for (int pimageNum = 0; pimageNum < 359; pimageNum++)
{
     // reading Positive Images from directory and resize it to 30x30
int ii = 0; // Current column in training_mat
for (int i = 0; i<posImage.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < posImage.cols; j++) {
        training_mat.at<float>(imagenum,ii++) = posImage.at<uchar>(i,j);
imagenum++;
    }
}
training_Labels.push_back(1.0);
}

for (int nimageNum = 0; nimageNum < 171; nimageNum++)
{
     // reading Nagative Images from directory and resize it to 30x30
int ii = 0; // Current column in training_mat
for (int i = 0; i<nagImage.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nagImage.cols; j++) {
        training_mat.at<float>(imagenum,ii++) = nagImage.at<uchar>(i,j);
imagenum++;
    }
}
training_Labels.push_back(-1.0);
}

Mat(training_Labels).copyTo(labels);
labels.convertTo(labels, CV_32FC1);

 CvSVMParams SVM_params;
    SVM_params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    SVM_params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR; //CvSVM::LINEAR;
    SVM_params.degree = 0;
    SVM_params.gamma = 3;
    SVM_params.coef0 = 0;
    SVM_params.C = 1;
    SVM_params.nu = 0;
    SVM_params.p = 0;
    SVM_params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 0.03);
    //Train SVM


    LinearSVM svmClassifier;
    svmClassifier.train(training_mat, labels, Mat(), Mat(), SVM_params);
    svmClassifier.save("D:\\svmClassifier.yml");

HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.winSize = Size(8, 8);
std::vector<float> support_vector;

FileStorage fs;
    fs.open("D:\\svmClassifier.yml", FileStorage::READ);

    fs["support_vectors"] >> support_vector;

hog.setSVMDetector(support_vector);

vector< Rect> found,found_filtered;
Size padding(Size(0, 0));
Size winStride(Size(8, 8));

cv::Mat test=cv::imread("testimage.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
// actual size of test image is 1024x768 which I resize to 400x 300
hog.detectMultiScale(test, found, 0.0, winStride, padding, 1.01, 0);

cout<<""found particles"<< found.size() ;  // it is always zero

size_t i, j;
    for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = found[i];
        for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
            if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
                break;
        if (j==found.size())
            found_filtered.push_back(r);
    }

    for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
        r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
        r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
        r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.06);
        r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.9);
        rectangle(test, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
    }

    imshow("detected particles", test);
    waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete - as you have linked to your training data, it would be nice to have code we can run. can you post the whole file showing what libraries you are using. Where are you getting `LinearSVM` from? Also your image resizing code. Can you check the google drive, `"testimage.bmp" is not included (other test images are).

Comment: @foundry I am using opencv function for resize the image and for testimage.bmp please check the google drive again.. 
I can't post the whole code here but this is somehow the complete code.
I don't have any compiler or runtime error. the problem is I am doing something wrong maybe in SVM training or HOG, that's why the object found vector size is always zero.

Comment: Yes I can see the testImage now. However  you are still missing some essential information. What is this type `LinearSVM`? I cannot find it anywhere in the openCV documentation, either for v3 or v2.x. Is it [this](http://www.linearsvm.com/)? Is it some custom class you have made? This code really isn't complete, it is not even a complete function. For this kind of problem, it really helps if you can provide running (albeit broken) code so we can explore the breakage.

Comment: yes you're right. sorry I forget to post the LInear SVM class. I have edit the post please check the post again. I used this to extract primal form. I hope now my code is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't managed to get your classifier to work, but I have found the cause of your current issue.

I have put up a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/foundry/e574266d8bf3efc9bfb8) so you can check it out. I have used my own filereading methods to read in the images, so you will have to make one or two changes so that it works for you.

The reason that you get no found objects is because your classifier vector is empty. *That* is due to incorrect reading of the node from the yml file. 'support_vectors' is a subnode of 'my_svm'. You were trying to read it as a top-level node, and were getting back an empty vector.

There are also a couple of other errors in the filereading loops which I have fixed (marked `FIXED`) - at least, they seemed incorrect to me.

This still won't correctly classify (yet). There is some issue with the format of your support vectors array, which breaks the hog descriptor.

So you'll need to put a bit more work into this, but hopefully this moves you in the right direction.

I have added a slider to the output window. When you get the classifier to work, you can change the scaleFactor with the slider which should yield interesting variation in the results.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your all consideration... I have tried your code and FIXED the issues which you have mentioned and my classifier vector is not empty It contains 901 elements same as generated by your code. May be this issue is because of to SVM parameters. I have studied in detail about the support vector and how to use it in HOG but no results yet.. still getting no found objects :( but again thanks a lot @foundry.
I will update you if I find some solution.